# How to select various-length sections from list using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list (it could be a list of complex type, but for better idea explanation I will use string).

Edit:
Please, do not provide me split method solutions. They are completely useless. I have a list of complex type, string is only simplification

There are some repeated elements which indicates start of new section. Every section may have various-length.

Example:

(in my real problem - every string is a part of complex type)

```
class Complex
{
  public string Header { get; set; }
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

start
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
start
1
2
3
start
1
2
3
4
5
6
start
1
start
1
2

I would like to get all possible lists using LINQ. I mean

- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
- 1 2 3
- 1 2 3 4 5 6
- 1
- 1 2

How to do this using only LINQ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I am able to do this without LINQ. I have a list of objects. But if algorithm will work with string, it will work with everything else

Comment: This works only for strings

Answer (score 4):

use [GroupAdjacent](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/GroupAdjacent.cs?r=03799046f7e508c90c3733212bf6da57e55191ad&spec=svn4d5e1077d9d67f0345f6a64d62a6ef571d8eceb2) method, provided my [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

```
var strings = new []{"start","1","2","3","4","5","6","7",
                     "start","1","2","3",
                     "start","1","2","3","4","5","6",
                     "start","1",
                     "start","1","2"};

strings.GroupAdjacent(v => v != "start")
       .Where(grp => grp.Key) //skip "start" items
       .ForEach(groupItems => Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", groupItems)));
```

prints:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3
1 2 3 4 5 6
1
1 2
```

MoreLinq also provides [Split](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Split.cs?r=cbb78b95fd8609e5e5fb15798e14385357828ddc) extension method:

```
strings.Split("start")
       .Where(grp => grp.Any()) //skip first item as empty collection 
       .ForEach(groupItems => Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", groupItems)));
```

will print the same

Comment: I can use only pure Linq, no additional libraries

Comment: @BorysławBobulski may I ask why is that the case? (MoreLinq is open source, so you can use their sources, compile and run)

Comment: I try to minimize code length, this is very simple issue. Please forget about this question, look here for new version of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233681/how-to-select-various-length-sections-from-list-of-complex-type-using-linq

Comment: @BorysławBobulski it is preferable to clarify your existing question, not post a new version of it

Comment: No, because if question has minus reputation, there is no way to encourage anyone to find solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
YourList.Split('start').ToList();
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: No, it won't. The problem is not with strings, but with complex objects. For example, I have a class with one Header property, and there is a string.