# How to select sections of differing lengths from list using LINQ only

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a List of a type named 'Complex':

```
List<Complex> list = new List<Complex>();
...
class Complex
{
  public string Header { get; set; }
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

There are some repeated headers in list, and these indicate the start of new sections. Each section may be of a different length, as shown below:

```
start 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 start 1 2 3 start 1 2 3 4 5 6 start 1 start 1 2
```

I would like to get all possible sublists of type Complex using LINQ; that is, all objects with headers, as follows:

- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
- 1 2 3
- 1 2 3 4 5 6
- 1
- 1 2

How can I accomplish this using LINQ only?

edit:
List is created during html page parsing

```
<tr>
                                                <td>00:00<!--//-00:00--></td>
<td>15:00<!--//-00:00--></td>
<td class="txt_left"><a href="">News</a></td>
<td><a href="/TsV2/TV_Video_On.asp?PROG_CODE=TVCR0114">
<img src="/images/new/sub_new/icon_play01_off.gif" alt="play"  class="rollover"/></a></td>

</tr>

<tr>
                                                <td>00:15<!--//-00:00--></td>
<td>15:15<!--//-00:00--></td>
<td class="txt_left">
<a href="Tv_Pagego.asp?PROG_CODE=TVCR0556">Nice one</a></td>
<td><a href="/TV2w/TV_2Video_On.asp?PROG_CODE=TVCR0556"><img src="/images/new/sub_new/icon_play01_off.gif" alt="play"  class="rollover"/></a></td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Is the header a unique value or always the same ("start")?

Comment: In the question it says "Repeated headers", have you tried .GroupBy(x => x. Header)?

Comment: @DaveWilliams Group by isn't going to work in this case.

Comment: Do you need to use LINQ ? Its one simple run trough classic for cycle.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Why not? If the headers are just those listed in the question it would work otherwise the question should be more clear...

Comment: @DaveWilliams GroupBy would need unique keys to separate the lists, if the deciding header is always "start", then you won't get the groupings you need. This is what I was trying to determine with my initial question.

Comment: Ok. Example: Complex c0 = new Complex() { Header = "start" }. list.Add(c0); Complex c1 = new Complex() { Header = "00:23" }. list.Add(c1);  Complex c2 = new Complex() { Header = "00:33" }. list.Add(c2); Complex c3 = new Complex() { Header = "start" }. list.Add(c3); etc...

Comment: So you try to tell me, it is not possible to do this using LINQ?

Comment: Of course it would be as I said in the first place. I think that there was a small misunderstanding about the headers from the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select various-length sections from list using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233050/how-to-select-various-length-sections-from-list-using-linq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var seq = new object[] {"start", 1, 2, 3, 4, "start", 1, 2, 3, "start", 1, 2, "start", 1};

            var no = 0;

            var test = (from i in seq select new {SeqNo = (i.ToString() == "start" ? no++ : no), Item = i}).Where( x => x.Item.ToString() != "start").GroupBy( y => y.SeqNo ).Select( z => z.ToArray()).ToArray();


        }
```

or

```
var test = (from i in seq
                       group i by i.ToString() == "start" ? ++no : no into g
                       select g.Where( gi => gi.ToString() != "start" ).ToArray()
                       ).ToArray()
                       ;
```

**ToArray** statements are not necessery

Comment: Well done for providing a "linq" solution, but I'd still advise not touching it as it's a bugger to read! :-)

Comment: You are a genius! :D It works. 
var test = (from i in fulllist select new {SeqNo = (i.Header == "start" ? no++ : no), Item = i}).Where( x => x.Item.Header != "start").GroupBy( y => y.SeqNo ).Select( z => z.ToArray()).ToArray();

Comment: You could also apply the iterator over the Linq Function `complexList.Select((complex, i) => new { Number = complex.Header.Equals("Start") ? i++ : i, Complex = complex })`

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear for me but here are some hints:

- Use .Distinct() to get unique results
- Try GroupBy(c => c.Header)
- Use string.Split to split string value if necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
var List = new List<Complex>()
{
    new Complex() { Header = "start" },
    new Complex() { Header = "00:23" },
    new Complex() { Header = "00:33" },
    new Complex() { Header = "start" }
};

var query = List.GroupBy(x => x.Header);
```

This should result in 3 IGroupings one with header "Start" one with "00:23" and one with "00:33"

More specificaly the query would return an IEnumerable> where the Keys would be your header. And the elements would be your type (Complex).

EDIT: Not what the question asked it seems however this is :)

```
var seq = new object[] {"start", 1, 2, 3, 4, "start", 1, 2, 3, "start", 1, 2, "start", 1}.ToList();

while(seq.Count() != 0)
{
    var Output = seq.SkipWhile(x => x.ToString() != "start").Skip(1).TakeWhile(x => x.ToString() != "start");
    seq.RemoveRange(0, Output.Count() +1);
}
```

I like it...

Comment: the order of addition is important. It is a list created during parsing html file.

Comment: This definitely doesn't give the desired output.

Comment: How does that affect the answer? Add them in whatever order you like... if you want to get the "sublists" with the same header they will be in the same order as the original list. At least I think so...

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Do you know the desired output? I am giving my answer as I understand from the question .It gives me the output I think he wants. If it is not the case then the person asking the questiong can give some further explanations an I will change my answer to suit.

Comment: The desired output, at least to my understanding, is written on the question. 4 groupings of a subset of the list, defined by when you encounter something saying "start".

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth now you put it that way I think you are correct. My apologies... would update my answer but not sure its possible with pure LINQ

Comment: And yet it is looking at the answer just posted by Yaugen!

Comment: @DaveWilliams Yes but I'd still not use it personally. The requirement for "just LINQ" has no functional benefit other than academic, and trying to maintain that code 3 months later might prove to be a nightmare. Readability trumps linqy goodness each time I'm afraid.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I think my updated answer is a reasonable solution without abusing linq and still maintaning readbility. Not pure linq either but I like it!